# Rename resource routes param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

More of an aesthetic problem, but here we go: In Rails 4 I'm overriding the `to_params` method in the usual way:

```
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_param
    slug
  end
end

class SongsController < ApplicationController
  def show
     Song.find_by slug: params[:id]
  end
end
```

It annoys me that the `slug` get assigned to the key `:id`. The reason for this is the call to `resources` in `config/routes.rb`:

```
resources :songs
```

which among others generates the following route:

```
song GET    /songs/:id(.:format)           songs#show
```

Is there a way to redefine the params key from :id to :slug *without* manually redefining every single route :)?

Comment: I think I understand your question, please try this: `resources :songs, param: :slug`

Comment: while this might look like an aesthetic problem, it's actually quite an issue. most real world applications don't want ids or at least also want friendly urls or UUIDs that are not guessable. as long as rails does not acknowledge that fakt, you should just stick to `id`. CONVENTION OVER CONFIGURATION!

Comment: Thanks, vee. But I think the `params` option rather adds an additional param to the route. It did not rename the `id` key for me. I guess I'll just live with it for now.